# Huffman Coding - Incorrect Codes

Tags: c++, huffman-code

Im trying to build a Huffman tree using an array. Everytime i combine two nodes, I add the new node to the array and sort it. My code works for some test cases but for others, it produces the wrong codes. Can someone please point me to the right direct in debugging? Thanks!

Here is a segment of my compress function.

```
while(tree->getSize() != 1)
{
    right = tree->getMinNode();
    left = tree->getMinNode();

    Node *top = new Node;
    top->initializeNode((char)1, left->getFrequency() + right->getFrequency(), left, right);

    tree->insertNode(top);
} // while

root = tree->getRootNode();
tree->encodeTree(root, number, 0);
tree->printCode(data);
```

The getMinNode() function returns the smallest node and after I insert the node that combines the 2 smallest nodes, I use qsort to sort the array. This is the function i use to sort the array.

I am sorting: 1st with frequency, 2nd with data. If the node is not a leaf node, meaning it does not contain one of the characters presented in the uncompressed data, I find the minimum data in the subtree using the function getMinData().

```
int Tree::compareNodes(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if( ((Node *)a)->frequency < ((Node *)b)->frequency )
       return -1;
    if( ((Node *)a)->frequency > ((Node *)b)->frequency )
        return 1;
    if( ((Node *)a)->frequency == ((Node *)b)->frequency )
    {
        if( ((Node *)a)->isLeafNode() && ((Node *)b)->isLeafNode() )
        {
            if( (int)((Node *)a)->data < (int)((Node *)b)->data )
                return -1;
            if( (int)((Node *)a)->data > (int)((Node *)b)->data )
                return 1;
        } // if
        else
        {
            int minA, minB;
            minA = (int)((Node *)a)->data;
            minB = (int)((Node *)b)->data;

            if(!((Node *)a)->isLeafNode())
                getMinData(a, &minA);
            if(!((Node *)b)->isLeafNode())
                getMinData(b, &minB);

            if(minA < minB)
                return -1;
            if(minA > minB)
                return 1;
        }// else
    } // if

    return 0;
} // compareNodes()
```

Say if for example, i have the following text.

I agree that Miss Emily Grierson is a symbol of the Old South. Her house and family traditions support this suggestion. However, I do not see her as a victim of the values of chivalry, formal manners, and tradition. I consider these values to have positive effects of a person rather have negative impacts. If for any reason that had made Emily isolate herself from her community and ultimately kill a man she likes, it would be herself. She acts as her own antagonist in the story because she does not have conflict with anyone else except herself. She makes herself become a “victim,” as in being friendless and miserable. The traditions and manners taught to her may have effects on her behavior but it is her attitude towards the outside world that separates her from the rest of the townspeople
\n

with the '\n' at the end. some of the characters i get the correct huffman codes, but some others i don't. Ascii 83('S'), 120('x'), 84('T') are some of the characters with the wrong codes. Thanks!

Comment: Too much code without even a hint as to what is not working. You need to AT LEAST provide sample input which is not correct.

Comment: You need to provide an example of the input and the "wrong codes" produced.

Comment: @DwayneTowell, I have edited the question and added an example. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want the same node for both `left`and ´right´? And why the void pointers and casting?

Comment: @molbdnilo Its not the same node for both left and right because every time getMinNode is called, the size of the node array decreases by 1, and the next time is it called again, the node return is the next smallest node on the array. The void pointers and casting are because the compareNodes() function is used for qsort.

Comment: @user3304763 OK, I've grown to expect `getXXX` methods to not mutate anything.

Comment: Your sample input is way too big. Find a minimal case.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I have tried it with some shorter input but the program seems to be working fine with those. Its only when i feed it with larger input when it starts to print out the wrong codes..

Comment: Try removing one letter from your current input. Does it still produce wrong output? Yes: repeat. No: remove a different letter, repeat. Continue until you have the smallest possible input. Post that.